# Angular components not showing up on browser

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-components

I’m learning  Angular  and I’ve noticed that my components are not rendering in the browser they were rendering at first but idk what happend. The components seem to be loaded correctly according to the DevTools Elements panel, but they are not visible in the browser. Here’s what I see in DevTools:

`<body><app-root _nghost-ng-c582792440="" ng-version="17.0.9"><h1 _ngcontent-ng-c582792440="">Hello world</h1><app-rooms _ngcontent-ng-c582792440="" _nghost-ng-c1015427938=""><app-header _ngcontent-ng-c1015427938="" _nghost-ng-c1823500013=""><h1 _ngcontent-ng-c1823500013=""></h1></app-header></app-rooms></app-root><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script</body>`

I’ve checked the console for errors and there are none.I’ve also ensured that all my components are properly declared in my @NgModule decorator and that the selectors used in my templates match the selectors defined in my components. My routes are correctly configured and I’m correctly importing any necessary modules, services, or other dependencies.

I think everythink is right with code they were rendering and i also removed all the changes from the code Despite all this, my components are still not showing up in the browser. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: We'd need to actually see some code to tell you if you're doing anything wrong. All we can tell you so far is that you seem to have an empty page that just says 'Hello world'. I mean, sure, it suggests it's loading a `rooms` component, but other than containing an `h1` element (which nothing in it), that's it...